# SQLITE: Replace without auto_increment

Tags: sqlite, replace, unique

I have a sqlite table: 
for example

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (id integer primary key, number integer unique, name text);
```

However, i need to make REPLACE without autoincrementing the id field when it updates.

For example : THE TABLE IS EMPTY

```
REPLACE INTO TEST (null, 23, 'Bill');
REPLACE INTO TEST (null, 52, 'Jack');
```

When I execute the query, `SELECT * FROM TEST;` I get...

```
1|23|Bill
2|52|Jack
```

if I do...

```
REPLACE INTO TEST VALUES (null, 52, 'John');
```

from the query `SELECT * FROM TEST;`  i get..

```
1|23|Bill
3|52|John
```

but i need...

```
1|23|Bill
2|52|John
```

Does anyone have an idea on how do do this ?

Comment: Your question implies that `number` is the primary key. Why then do you have another primary key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible with a single command.

`REPLACE` always deletes the old record (if it exists) before inserting the new one.

To keep the autoincrement value, you have to keep the record.
That is, update the old record in place, and insert a new one only if no old one existed:

```python
db.execute("UPDATE Test SET Name = 'John' WHERE Number = 52")
if affected_records == 0:
    db.execute("INSERT INTO Test(Number, Name) VALUES(52, 'John')")
```

Answer (score 3):

Late answer for SQLite3 users: Now it is possible, but it implies a lot of writing if you have a lot of fields.

Instead of REPLACE you can use INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (number, name) VALUES (52, 'John')
ON CONFLICT(number) DO UPDATE
SET number=excluded.number, name=excluded.name;
```

You then get your result:

```
1|23|Bill
2|52|John
```

But you need to specify, for each field, that you want to replace the value in the table by the value from the row which violates the unique constraint (called "excluded").

Unfortunately there is no way (to my knowledge) to update all the fields but one.