# Sqlite INSERT OR REPLACE INTO not working as expected

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to figure out what the problem is for hours :(

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   title TEXT,
   parent INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
   content TEXT,
   time INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY(category) REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY(parent) REFERENCES pages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   UNIQUE(title) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

The insert query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO pages (title, parent, content, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

`title` should be unique, so if it founds a record with the same title it should replace it. It gets replaced, but the ID changes too! This is a problem because all other records that were having a parent field that was pointing to the old ID are getting removed :(

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ID is set to auto increment so when you replace something,the ID also changes.because replacing means deleting the old row and inserting a new one.
I don't know if sqlite has INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: ok that makes sense :/ I guess I need to check if the records exists and do update query, otherwise insert..

Comment: Here another thread i found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942109/sqlite-replace-without-auto-increment

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to replace the type TEXT to

```
VARCHAR
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I think" are not answers but more of a comment. Please elaborate why this would be the answer to his problem.